# How do I bookmark several lines with a regular expression?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have this regular expression that finds a line with the world "Title Sequence" matches the 2 previous lines above it, the next 1 to 5 lines below it and finally a line with a year in it (four digits).

```
((^.*$)\r\n){2}(^.*Title Sequence.*$\r\n)((.*\r\n){1,5}^.*, \d{4}.*$)
```

This works fine but when I try to bookmark all these lines int notepad++ it bookmarks only the first line of every block. How do I make it bookmark every line in the block so I can then delete everything but the bookmarked lines?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it in one go, but since it's only 8 lines you are interested in, there is a solution that would take 8 iterations.

You can use the \K operator "[Keep The Text Matched So Far out of The Overall Regex Match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)".

So in the example

```
b
a
b
```

You would fist bookmark this, for the first line

```
b\r\na\r\nb
```

Then this, for the second

```
b\r\n\Ka\r\nb
```

And this for the third

```
b\r\na\r\n\Kb
```